# Using Automapper to create an array of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, automapper

I have the following code in a C# MVC project that uses Automapper but I need it to return an array of arrays to be processed by Jquery Datatables.

I have at present done it using a Linq solution as detailed below but wondered if there is a solution using Automapper?

**Automapper**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Job, IndexJobViewModel>()
    .ForMember(jvm => jvm.JobNumberFull,
    expression => expression.ResolveUsing(j => string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", j.JobNumberPrefix, j.JobNumber, j.JobNumberYear)));
```

**LINQ**

```
 var jobs = db.Jobs.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(j => new[] 
     { 
         j.JobNumber.ToString(),
         j.JobNumberYear.ToString(),
         String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", j.JobNumberPrefix, j.JobNumber, j.JobNumberYear),
         j.JobPriority.ToString(),
         j.EntityPriority.PriorityLevel,
         j.JobDescription
     });

return Json(new
{
   Data = jobs.ToArray()
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Update**

Thanks to ThinTim pointing me in the right direction I came up with a solution that works, although it doesn't really reduce the code from my Linq version, just another way of doing it! I had hoped to have be able to use AutoMapper map from my Job model to my IndexViewModel to give me only the fields I require and then create an array of arrays from that.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Job, string[]>().ConstructUsing(
    j => new string[] 
    { 
         j.JobID.ToString(),
         j.JobNumber.ToString(), 
         j.JobNumberYear.ToString(), 
         string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", j.JobNumberPrefix, j.JobNumber, j.JobNumberYear), 
         j.JobPriority.ToString(), 
         j.EntityPriority.PriorityLevel,
         j.JobDescription 
     });

var jobs = db.Jobs.Where(j => j.OperationID == operationId).ToList();
var jobsArray = jobs.Select(job => Mapper.Map<string[]>(job)).ToArray();                          

return Json(new
{
Data = jobsArray
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6179903/2744839) seems to have what you're looking for.

Comment: ThinTim, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have come up with a solution that works and have added this to my original post. I was really hoping to have to avoid detailing each field and using the Automapper magic!